# Android Color.parseColor gives different value to R.color.xyz

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a color value in my app via:

```
R.color.colorAccent
```

Which is correctly defined as:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

However on running the app it gives a dark almost gray like color. When I use

```
Color.parseColor("#FF4081")
```

it gives the correct redish/pink color. Is this expected behaviour? Should I be required to turn R.color.colorAccent back into a hex value to then run it through Color.parseColor to get the color I expect?

Comment: If you get a dark gray color when you do not expect it, it is likely because you are using the ID _as_ the color. Rather, use the ID to _find_ the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.color.ColorAccent` returns a resource id, not the actual color.  The system still recognizes the id as valid, and displays a color based on the id, not the hex value.

You need to do something like this

```
view.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually parse the color into an Android color, rather then straight up referencing the resource int.

Use

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
```

or

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent);
```

in the Support Library